# Is Paypal the best solution for payment gateway for a website?

Tags: web-development, website-design, paypal

I have a realty website that needs a payment gateway for their property reservation. The reservation fee range from $500-$600 and about 5-6 people per month. I was wondering if Paypal is the best solution for accepting Payment. What will be the Pros and Cons using Paypal.

Paypal was my first choice because It's easy to integrate on my existing website and I wouldn't be minding so much on the security.

P.S.
It's not a part of the question, But If you can site some realty website that accept payment and would be a good inspiration. It would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any of your own research? Their pricing is right on their website.

Comment: I did found the pricing on their site a few minutes after posting it here. I'll just edit my question. Thanks John

Comment: When you say "payment gateway" do you mean a solution like PayPal where they are the merchant account and gateway? Or do you mean like Authorize.Net where they are the gateway and you have your own merchant account? Telling us what country you're in also helps as the answer will very based on your location.

Comment: @john It's for a client in Malaysia. Both can work with me, as long as it handles the payment and it's secure. Another factor is it needs to be simple. that I easy to deploy on the site. I find paypal to easily integrate on websites. I'm not sure of Authorize.net yet.

Comment: Authorize.Net is not available to Malaysian businesses so it's not even an option. You will need a company like Payal as true merchant accounts are not available in Malaysia at all.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll try to explore about Authorize.net for future projects. btw, I can't find the the supported countries in both Google and Authorize.net. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

The cost of Authorize.Net includes a 1 time setup fee ($100), then a $20 a month fee plus an additional $10 monthly for the reoccurring billing plugin. The benefit being it has a fixed cost of $0.10 per transaction. Paypal pro is free to activate plus $20 a month and 2.2-2.9% +$0.30 per transaction.

Generally if your around $3,400 or higher in transactions a month you'd want to consider Authorize.net or if you need the other features they provide such as directly linking into your merchant account and POS processing*.

*Paypal does do POS processing but it's not as smooth to integrate from my personal experience.

Comment: Authorize.Net's actual fees will vary by reseller. It's possible to get a free account setup and I've also seen setup fees of $295 as well. That 10¢ transaction fee can also be waived for the first 250 transactions if you get the right reseller. Their fees are in addition to the merchant account fees which make per transaction fees almost always higher then Paypal.

Comment: You may want to edit your answer as it is no longer valid based on their comments.

Comment: How is it not valid based on his comments?

Comment: Authorize.Net is not available in Malaysia

Comment: My answer is still valid at explaining a comparison to different types of payment gateways. I think that's a decent resource to keep on the site in case someone else comes along searching for similar answers and isn't from Malaysia.

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated Authorize.Net into an E-Commerce website for credit card transactions. I believe you can also integrate Google Checkout as an option.

Answer (score 0):

i use fanapay.com as a payment gateway ,they accept most web sites.
there gateway easy and secure plus no set fees or monthly fees only per transaction.
they accept site and users worldwide.